# Wordpress - Child Theme Template Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've created a custom page(template), in fact, at this moment, I did a blank page, like, page-newpage.php(inside child theme dir structure), I've also already created a page called "newpage" and it is partially working, I mean, the page runs ok, but with parent theme(beClinic) header and footer.

Can someone give me a clue about how to remove theme header and footer?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `page-newpage.php` may be you have added below code.

`get_header();` - This call header.php file of the active theme/parent theme

`get_footer();` - This call footer.php file of the active theme/parent theme

In order to remove header and footer, you need to remove above functions from your your `page-newpage.php`
But if you remove, then WordPress functions will not work in your `page-newpage.php`

So what you can do is create custom header and footer for your `page-newpage.php`

go through [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/#user-contributed-notes) in details

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it but it's not working yet...I've created a new header-newpage.php and load it inside template page(child theme) with get_header( 'newpage' );. The result is: Parent theme header is still loading and after that the newpage header.